# change active cell fill color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with some protected sheets.
Users enter data into specific cells of each sheet.
I want the active cell background color to change - for example to red - when it is highlighted and back to the original color when deselected.
I would like to find a macro to assign it to the workbook instead of each worksheet.

I think this code is useful but since I'm a beginner I don't know which parameter should be changed to fit my demand.

```vba
Sub ColorCells()
    Dim Data As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ekandari")
    Set Data = currentsheet.Range("C5:D5,F5:M5,L9")
    For Each cell In Data
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please show us some code attempt you did before asking for help

Comment: Wanna give me an exam my friend? if i knew the answer i wouldn't ask again. I searched on net and found some but none of'em fixed my problem.

Comment: ? Help others reproduce the problem? What is exactly your probleme? SO is not a "write code for you services". After this is just an advice so someone might answer you question.. Not that I care so much

Comment: You must detect the activation of the cell. look at private sub in the module ThisWorkbook such as `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` to apply an action to the whole workbook

Comment: In each sheet i have some cell that get data by TransferData macro but users should put data in some cells manually and i dont want use sub code cuz i dont want use button to change active cell color. i wanted paste a code here but couldn't nor Ctrl+K nither 4 space strikes took action to specify my code

Comment: Thanks for your edit

Comment: When searching for routines in Excel, you should start with the words "VBA EXCEL" in google and then what you are looking for.  Example, "vba excel change active cell color".  Try that in google and you will find about 50 routines.  The simplest way to do what you want is to put the following in your worksheet module 
`Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
 ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
`

Answer (score 0):

Mansour, this should help.  Unfortunately it does not work for the entire workbook.  You will need to add this code to each sheet in the workbook.  If you do not have a password then you will need to delete the "password" from the second line

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"

    On Error Resume Next
    Range("PrevCell").Interior.ColorIndex = 0

    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    With ActiveWorkbook.Names("PrevCell")
        .RefersTo = ActiveCell
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
End Sub
```

The only change you need to make is if you don't want the active color to be red, then change the 3 to whichever color index you want to use.

Comment: It does work on protected sheets.  The second line that says 'ActiveSheet.Uprotect "password"' is what unprotects the sheet.  If you are not using a password then you can just delete the "password" portion.  If you are using a password then replace the word password with your real password.  Second, do the cells have different colors besides white?  This code automatically changes the deselected cell to white.

Comment: 1-You are right, but i commented to your post before your edition. 2- At first i thought it changes to **no fill** cuz white looks like that. 3-Are you sure your code returns the original active cell color after deselection?

Comment: You know I have not gotten my answer yet.Originally some cells are for example green, some are blue on my sheet.. but after applying the code all colors change to relevant color code not to the original color.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest code i've found that sets background and active cell colors.
note: put it in (Thisworkbook)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Password"
Sh.UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 27   'change colorindex to select background color
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 32         'change colorindex to select active cell color
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password"
End Sub
```

If you don't use protected sheets remove

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Password"

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password"
```

Comment: I wanted to change only active cell color but couldn't find the right code.If anyone knows please fix it